# Preview image before upload VueJs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I try to preview a image before upload, I want  to dispaly a small one, and on click to be full size, but till now it didn't work. I am using [vue-upload-component](https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/en/), file.thumb from them also didn't work.
[image]

```
data() {
    return {
        url:null,
    }
}
watch: {
    files: {
        handler: function(){
            this.files.forEach((file,index) =>{
                const file = e.target.file[0];
                this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                console.log('Files:',this.files);
            })
        },
    }
}

//First try found on stack
<div id="preview">
    <img v-if="url" :src="url" />
</div> 

//This is from them , but is not working.
<img v-if="file.thumb" :src="file.thumb" width="40" height="auto" />
<span v-else>No Image</span>
```

**UPDATE**
  Now the small image it works, I just need to add some things form that library.
  Now I just need to preview full size img hen click.

```
<img v-if="file.thumb" :src="file.thumb" width="40" height="auto" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this throw: identifier 'file' already declared?

Comment: In fact, I do. I must change the name.

Comment: did this solve your issue?

Comment: No, I solve this, with what I write in post on UPDATE. And I solve the second one about preview on full screen.

Comment: ah ok ^^ next time just answer your own question ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `this` from the forEach scope, try initializing the global `ViewModel` to be able to access the data params, like this :

```
watch: {
    files: {
        handler: function(){
            let vm = this;
            this.files.forEach((file,index) =>{
                const file = e.target.file[0];
                vm.url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                console.log('Files:',vm.files);
            })
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: this.files works just fine, if I comment the 2 line above, I don't think I need vm variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
handler: function(){
  this.files.forEach((file,index) =>{
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.url = e.target.result; //Base64 string
        }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file. , for any. Also I must rename "file" because I get error, for duplicate value.